# Do the transfinite powers of an ideal in the radical always reach 0?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nonnoetherian

This is true in the Noetherian case by Nakayama's lemma. Is it true in general?

Less tersely, let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$ be an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical. Define the transfinite powers $I^\alpha$ for $\alpha$ an ordinal inductively as ($I^1 = I$ and) $I^{\alpha+1} = I \cdot I^\alpha$, and $I^\alpha = \cap_{\beta < \alpha} I^\beta$ at limit ordinals.

This is a decreasing sequence of ideals, so it must eventually stabilize: i.e. there is $\kappa$ such that $I^\lambda = I^\kappa$ for all $\lambda \geq \kappa$,and in particular we have $I \cdot I^\kappa = I^\kappa$. If $I^\kappa$ is finitely generated (and in particular if $R$ is Noetherian), then by Nakayama's lemma, $I^\kappa = 0$ because $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$.

But is this true in the non-Noetherian case? That is, if $R$ is non-Noetherian and $I \subseteq \mathrm{rad}(R)$, then do we have $I^\kappa = 0$ for sufficiently large $\kappa$?

Comment: No: any local ring that isn't a field and whose (nonzero!) maximal ideal is its own square (e.g., the valuation ring of an algebraic closure of the fraction field of a complete discrete valuation ring) is a counterexample.

Comment: @nfdc23 Thanks! I would gladly accept this as an answer. It's reassuring to realize that in this case we can easily see the violation of Noetherianity by looking at the ideals $v^{-1}([0,1-\epsilon))$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$, where $v$ is the valuation.